# Prove by Contradiction: if $4\mid a^2 + b^2$, then $a$ and $b$ are not both odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove by Contradiction

> Suppose $a, b \in Z$. If $4|(a^2 + b^2)$, then $a$ and $b$ are not both odd.

So the contradiction: Assume $4|(a^2 + b^2)$, where $a$ and $b$ are both odd.

Then $a=2k+1$, $b=2l +1$

And then I substitute it into the equation and the result is something like this? $4|4(k^2 + k +l^2 + l) + 2$

What do I do next to prove this?

Comment: Aren't you done? Congruence to 2 mod 4 means it isn't divisible by 4.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Note that $a|b$ iff $a|(b+n a)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $(k^2 + k + l^2 + l)$ is an integer, you have $4|4(k^2 + k + l^2 + l) + 2 - 4(k^2 + k + l^2 + l)$, where we have used the above formula with $n = -(k^2 + k + l^2 + l)$. This simplifies to $4|2$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why is $n = (k2+k+l2+l)$ and not $4(k2+k+l2+l)+2$?

Comment: @Kingle Because if $n = 4(k^2 + k + l^2 + l) + 2$, then the above formula gives $4|(4(k^2 + k + l^2 + l) + 2 + (4(k^2 + k + l^2 + l) + 2)4)$ which doesn't help us. However I was wrong too; $n = -(k^2 + k + l^2 + l)$. We need the negative sign so it will cancel with the $4(k^2 + k + l^2 + l)$ term.