# Suppose that $ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ If 4 divides $ a^2 + b^2$, then $a$ and $b$ are not odd.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

I am trying to prove old test exercises and this one is resisting me.

I know you can believe that I meant $a^ 2 + b ^ 2$ is divisible by 4, but no, in the test it says that 4 is divisible by $a ^ 2+ b^2$.

Suppose that $ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$  If 4 is divisible by $ a^2 + b^2$, then $a$ and $b$ are not odd.

I started like this:

Suppose that a and b are even, then $a = 2m$ and $b = 2n$ for some $m,n \in \mathbb{Z} $.

Thus  $$ a^2 = (2m)^2 \ \mbox{and}\ \  b^2= (2n)^2$$
$$ a ^2 + b^2= (2m)^2 + (2n)^2$$
$$ a^2 + b^2 = (4 m^2 + 4n^2) = 2(2m^2+2n^2) $$

Now $$2m ^ 2 + 2n^2\in \mathbb{Z} = k$$ Then

$$ a^2+b^2= 2k$$

Is this a correct proof?/ Any better ways to prove this.

Sorry for the lousy English.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to assume $a$, $b$ odd, and derive a contradiction.

Comment: $a=b=1$ makes $2\mid 4$, and both $a$ and $b$ are odd. Or do you want $a^2+b^2=0\mod 4$?

Comment: Maybe that you want $a^2+b^2$ divisible by $4$ ?

Comment: No, in the test it says: If 4 is divisible by $a ^ 2 + b ^ 2$.  
Maybe it's a mistake. I will have to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume you mean $a^2 + b^2$ is divisible by $4$.

Assume $a, b$ are odd. Then $a^2 + b^2 = (2k +1)^2 + (2j+1)^2 = (4k^2 + 4k + 1) + (4j^2 + 4j + 1) = 2(2k^2 + 2j^2 + 2k + 2j + 1)$.

This is not divisible by $4$ since the highest power of $2$ is in the product is only $1$.

We have created a contradiction, so $a,b$ cannot both be odd and satisfy $a^2 + b^2$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: Just a quick comment. "This is not divisible by 4 since it is the product of an odd and even" is not a fair statement since there are numbers that are divisible by 4 and are the product of an "odd and even". The argument should be that the highest power of 2 that divides the sum is 1, thus 4 cannot divide it, or something of the sorts.

Comment: Ah, yes absolutely. Moved a little too quickly for my own good. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As Good Morning Captain wrote,
I assume you meant that
$a^2+b^2$
is divisible by $4$.

Consider the values
modulo $4$.
If $a$ is even,
$a=2n$,
then
$a^2 = 4n^2$
leaves a remainder of $0$.
If $a$ is odd,
$a=2n+1$,
then
$a^2 = 4n^2+4n+1 = 4(n^2+n)+1$
leaves a remainder of $1$.

Since each of $a^2$ and $b^2$
can have remainders of
only $0$ or $1$,
their sum can only have
remainders of
$0, 1$, or $2$
and the first
($0$)
happens only when
both are even.

Answer (score 0):

I did a more thorough investigation and I found this proof.

Prove by contradiction

Assume $4|(a^2+b^2)$, where a and b are both odd.

Then $a=2m+1$, $b=2n+1$

Substitute in the equation and  $4|4(m^2+m+n^2+n)+2$

We know that $a|b$ if $a|(b+xa) \forall x \in \mathbb{z}$. Since $(m^2+m+n^2+n)$ is an integer, you have $4|4(m^2+m+n^2+n)+2−4(m^2+m+n^2+n)$ where we have used the above formula with $x = -(m^2 + m + n^2 + n)$. This simplifies to $4|2$, which is a contradiction.

This proof was done by user John Colanduoni in this post [Proving by Contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290330/proving-by-contradiction)

I will proceed to put my post as a duplicate.

Comment: Wait!  You have been stressing the fact that the test said that $4$ is divisible by $a^2+b^2$, rather than the other way around, even after several people commented that it was probably the latter, and not the former. But you kept saying it was the former ... but now in the answer you post yourself you *do* prove the latter?!?

Comment: Excuse me, I would like a clarification of the mathematical notation: 4 | (a ^ 2 + b ^ 2) is the same as a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 divisible by 4. I'm just learning the notation and that coupled with my bad English makes harder to understand.

Comment: $4 | a^2 + b^2$ indeed means that $a^2+b^2$ is divisible by $4$. You can also say that $4$ divides $a^2+b^2$

Comment: ok thanks for the information, all the problem about the writing of the exercise is that in my language it says, according to the translator, if 4 is divisible by a ^ 2 + b ^ 2. Again I apologize.

Comment: Well, when several people are commenting that it should probably be interpreted some way, and given how you're new to this and English is not your first language, maybe it would be a good idea not to insist that you have the correct interpretation .. anyway, it's all good: we're all here to learn! Please keep visiting this site :)

Answer (score 0):

I am with the other commenters that they probably meant that $a^2+b^2$ is divisible by $4$, because that would actually make for a somewhat interesting proof, whereas assuming that $4$ is divisible by $a^2+b^2$ really does not. In fact, if $4$ is divisible by $a^2+b^2$, then $a$ and $b$ *can* both be odd: they can both be $1$, and so $a^2+b^2=1+1-2$, which divides $4$.

OK, but you asked about your own proof: Well, it's pretty bad, to be honest. Your proof as a whole shows that $a^2+b^2$ is even if both $a$ and $b$ are even ... which is not only a trivial result, but most importantly it is not what you need to show: if you were thinking that your proof shows that if $a^2+b^2$ is even then both $a$ and $b$ must be even, you're wrong: $a$ and $b$ both being odd would also result in $a^2+b^2$ being even. And second, why should $a^2+b^2$ be even? The claim that $4$ is divisible by $a^2+b^2$ does not mean that $a^2+b^2$ is even: $1$ divides $4$, but is odd.

Comment: Yes, I realized how wrong I was.

Comment: @P.Saira OK, well, be more careful next time, please ...